# Negation of least significant bit (LSB) of signed integer

Tags: python, integer, bit-manipulation, signed

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6059487/15943951) answer demonstrates the negation of the LSB of an integer. This approach did not produce expected results when using negative (signed) integers. Let's look at some code:

```
a = 4

print()
print("a: " + str(a))
print("binary version of a: " + bin(a))

a = a | 1

print("binary version of a after negation of LSB: " + bin(a))
print("a after negation of LSB: " + str(a))
print()

b = 5

print("b: " + str(b))
print("binary version of b: " + bin(b))

b = b & ~1

print("binary version of b after negation of LSB: " + bin(b))
print("b after negation of LSB: " + str(b))
print()

c = -4

print("c: " + str(c))
print("binary version of c: " + bin(c))

c = c | 1

print("binary version of c after negation of LSB: " + bin(c))
print("c after negation of LSB: " + str(c))
print()

d = -5

print("d: " + str(d))
print("binary version of d: " + bin(d))

d = d & ~1

print("binary version of d after negation of LSB: " + bin(d))
print("d after negation of LSB: " + str(d))
```

The expected value of `c` after the negation of the LSB is -5 and not -3. Similarly, the expected value of `d` after the negation of the LSB is -4 and not -6. Why don't the actual values of `c` and `d` match their expected values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is python stores negative numbers as their two's complement, but doesn't print them out that way. Makes things pretty confusing! This post [here goes into more detail about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993519/python-representation-of-negative-integers), but we can see what's going on with a quick example:

-4 in binary is 0b11111100 (two's complement of 4)

1 is positive so in binary it is just 0b00000001

When you or those two together, you get:

0b11111101 which is the binary representation of -3 (two's complement)

I [used this site](https://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/) to find the two's complements, and it's worth noting that python integers are 32 bits instead of 8, so there will be 24 extra 1's in front of the negative/two's complement numbers and 24 extra 0's in front of the positive numbers (well as long as both are below abs(255))

Comment: To be more precise, your [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46993519/python-representation-of-negative-integers) states "CPython integer type stores the sign in a specific field of a structure. When performing a bitwise operation, CPython replaces negative numbers by their two's complement [...]". Although not in the question, it is interesting that you can't flip the MSB to turn the sign, because the bit width of Python's integer is flexible. Try `2**500`! Very special implementation.